# MySQL Workbench. Semicolon after comments before statement?

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench (Mac) if not to put semicolon before statement after comments, statement is not executed. So DROP, USE and CREATE TABLE not executing without ; and next statement gives error..

```
-- Comment
;DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbDataBase;

CREATE DATABASE dbDataBase
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
    COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'; -- define set of rules to compare characters

;USE dbDataBase;


-- Make a table
;CREATE TABLE Teams
(
     teamID    INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
     teamName  VARCHAR(50)      NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running it with and without the semicolons. It works OK for me. There's an error though in the `CREATE TABLE` statement since a comma is missing between the column definitions. Maybe this is what is causing confusion (along with the fact that in the status report the comment line is joined with the following but that's just a message).

I ran that in WB's latest version in Linux. Can you clarify if you are still getting this behavior?

Comment: Yes, still getting this behavior. Sorry for coma. Took me a long time to troubleshoot through homework and figure out why some statements do not execute. If delete semicolon before DROP, next statement CREATE DATABASE gives error - database cannot be created because already exists. If delete semicolon before USE -> CREATE TABLE don't execute, and if before CREATE TABLE - table simply not created. reinstall of workbench for latest version didn't help.

Comment: What WB version are you using?

Comment: I think you should file a bug in http://bugs.mysql.com/ so the issue can receive due attention. I also tried in Windows with WB 5.2.39 and couldn't repeat your results.

Comment: latest WB. Yes,- no issue on Win. Already filing bug, thanks for help!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the bug report. Can you [update it](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65230) to reflect which particular WB version exposes this bug? (5.2 is too vague, better 5.2.x since there are lots of changes between "minor" releases)

Comment: Problem cause found.

It has something to do with character encoding and editing sql file with multiple editors.
In my case if *.sql file is created with "Sublime" editor and then reopened/edited and saved with Workbench - issue persists. If to copy all text from workbench editor dialog, open new window in Workbench to create new query and paste text - queries run with no errors.

So problem has to do with parsing existing .sql files while opening them.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a bug report for this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67747

Your case works for me, but the following fails for me:

```
SELECT 1;
DELIMITER ;
/* comment */
SELECT 2;
```